# Is there a method to actually *visually design* twin views (landscape + portrait) in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, landscape

My current design calls for some cool animation between portrait and landscape views of the data. The data representation is fairly complex, so between graphical and data elements, there are probably about 30 buttons and labels on screen at once. I've created a very tightly designed interface... now I am laying out the elements for the landscape view. The only way I've found to do this so far is to actually lay out the landscape view in code, for instance:

```
-(void) positionViews {
    UIInterfaceOrientation destOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    if (destOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || destOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        //---if rotating into PORTRAIT mode
        timeBGbox.frame = CGRectMake(14, 88, 134, 14);
        targetTime.frame = CGRectMake(0, 99, 150, 29);
        energyBGbox.frame = CGRectMake(156, 88, 68, 14);
        targetEnergy.frame = CGRectMake(154, 99, 70, 29);
        speedBGbox.frame = CGRectMake(234, 88, 68, 14);
        targetSpeed.frame = CGRectMake(226, 99, 48, 29);
        speedLabel.frame = CGRectMake(264, 99, 40, 36);
    } else {
        //---if rotating to LANDSCAPE mode
        timeBGbox.frame = CGRectMake(156, 12, 152, 14);
        targetTime.frame = CGRectMake(160, 23, 150, 29);
        energyBGbox.frame = CGRectMake(156, 50, 68, 14);
        targetEnergy.frame = CGRectMake(154, 61, 70, 29);
        speedBGbox.frame = CGRectMake(234, 50, 74, 14);
        targetSpeed.frame = CGRectMake(228, 61, 48, 29);
        speedLabel.frame = CGRectMake(269, 61, 40, 36);
    }
}
```

This is a painstaking process, taking many trials to accomplish what I could do visually in seconds in IB. Currently, when I toggle between views in IB, and manually move elements in landscape mode, upon switching back to portrait, they are in the wrong place. I've used "springs and struts" as creatively as possible, but most of my elements need precise manual placement beyond the realm of AutoSizing.

My question is:
**Is there a toggle mode within IB that enables developing two graphical layouts of a view using the visual layout tools, or is numerical code the only way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an arbitrary number of views in your nib file.  You can call one of them "portrait view" (say, the one that is also hooked up to the "view" outlet of File's Owner), and one of them "landscape view".   Define them both as outlets in your UIViewController class:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;
```

lay out the fields in IB as you like.   The trick then is that you need double the outlets in your header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myLabel_portrait;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myLabel_landscape;
```

and in your code you need to keep both versions up to date.  Best is to just update both of them when you update one of them.

Then the code to autorotate is really easy, just:

```
if ( switchingToPortrait)
    self.view = self.portraitView;
else
    self.view = self.landscapeView;
```

Comment: +1. This has the drawback that the elements do not reshuffle to the new positions with an animation, you can only animate the transition between the whole views.

Comment: I'd do that with a third view, and in code place all the elements on the "temporary" rotating view using the frames of the portrait view, then animate the positions to that of the landscape view.   It still  uses the technique I desribe, it just expands on it.   You can still layout the landscape mode in IB for convenience.

Comment: thanks Bogatyr... for clarification: are you saying that every label & button I need to address needs both a _portrait and _landscape version? So basically throughout my code I will be updating 2 views simultaneously?

Comment: further... in your response to zoul, re: shuffle animation. If shuffle is a requirement, doesn't the third view still require manual coding of all positions? I was hoping for some intelligence in IB/iOS to 'morph' the field locations as the screen rotates.

Comment: Instead of using two different IBOutlets, maybe look into using IBOutletCollections?

Comment: @AcroYogi 1) yes.  I have not done that on a huge scale, however.  You could write property setter functions that dynamically choose between landscape/portrait based on the current orientation.  You could also just copy the object settings from portrait to landscape (or vice versa) at rotation time.   2) You would not need to place anything manually, you'd do it programmatically by placing objects based on their frame values, then doing a UIView animation from current position to destination position, for example

Comment: @Rengers I didn't know about IBOutletCollections, looks promising.  Can you choose which index you assign to on an object by object basis?   If so that may be the solution.  Probably was done just for this sort of thing.

Comment: Never worked with them but from the looks of it you can do that. Perhaps you can also use `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` to address all instances at the same time.

Comment: @Bogatyr: >just copy the object settings from portrait to landscape (or vice versa) at rotation time. That was just the 'eureka' I needed, Awesome!!!! Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is to have two views, and switch them in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do this in Interface Builder. Since the views are instantiated from the nib file, you would end up with two instances anyway.

As stated in the developer docs you could use layoutSubviews, or just use a custom method in your view controller like you have here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a landscape and portrait view in interface builder. For each orientation position your elements just like you want them. When you're happy with the look and feel, copy the coordinates into your "positionViews" method.